# What is a constant magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

Suppose I have a vector $\vec m$ which is defined to be a constant magnetic moment caused by an external magnetic field $\vec B$. In this context, is the meaning of constant refering to the components of $\vec m$? In other words is $\nabla \cdot \vec m=\vec 0$?

Comment: Are you referring to a magnetic moment in a material (spread out over space) or a point magnetic moment (like a tiny bar magnet)?

Comment: @taciteloquence From intuition I believe the problem statement refers to a point magnetic moment, although it does not say. What would be the difference in the constant moment between the two?

Comment: If the moment is *caused by an external magnetic field*, how is it constant?

Comment: @Vadim I took physics a while back and this is on a math problem that was given to me. I’m just wondering if the moment would be constant which would simplify some of the calculations. If that is not the case, what would constant refer to in this case?

Comment: @DMH16 normally, magnetic moment is just a vector, like charge is just a scalar. But it may be that here they mean *constant magnetization* - otherwise calculating divergence does not lake sense. In this case it is a vector field that is the same everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec m$ is a point magnetic dipole then it is not a function of space so there can be no gradient or divergence $ \nabla \cdot \vec m $. Perhaps what you mean is that in an external field, a dipole $\vec m$ will experience a force $F= \nabla ( \vec m \cdot \vec B)$, but you must do the dot product before you can take the gradient.

A local dipole is sort of like point charge for magnetism. Since there are no magnetic monopoles, a dipole is the simplest point source you can work with.

Source: take a look at Chapter 6 of Griffiths *Introduction to Electrodynamics*.